# Two id columns in sqlite android. Is it reasonable?

Tags: android, sqlite, iosched

I'm exploring source code of [google io schedule app](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleDatabase.java#L187) in education purposes. And I've noted an interesting thing.

In `ScheduleProvider` they use two `id` field. For example you can see that in table of blocks they use well known `BaseColumns._ID` and another `BlocksColumns.BLOCK_ID column`.

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Tables.BLOCKS + " ("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL," // BlocksColumns.BLOCK_ID == "block_id"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_START + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_END + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_SUBTITLE + " TEXT,"
            + "UNIQUE (" + BlocksColumns.BLOCK_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE)");
```

**So my question is:** Why do they need two columns for `id`?

I have one assumption. I think they don't want to refuse to standard tools like `SimpleCursorAdapter` so they created '_id' column. But they also want to do lots of `joins` without name conflicts so they created '%table%_id' column for each table. Am I right? If so I have another question. How they generate unique '%table%_id' for each new row?

---

**EDIT:**

I am asking not only for those who explored this code but also for experienced android programmers who probably came across the same scheme.

Comment: This is resonable. As you can see there is only one primary key. They might using it for any other purpose,